I consider moving Germany, or Czech. What are my chances to get a roof above the head?
I'm Ukrainian,
What are my chances to get no-cost, at least temporary space to live?
Countries considered are Germany, or Czech.

As mentioned by nvoigt, in 2022 the EU activated the temporary protection directive for residents of Ukraine. So you can consider more places than just Germany and Czechia, and more factors than just emergency housing. Check where your professional credentials are most useful, for instance.

germany
(I have no idea about the situation in the Czech Republic)
The official site from the German government is:
https://www.germany4ukraine.de/hilfeportal-de
You can switch it to English or Ukrainian (actually, the link directly to Ukrainian is: https://www.germany4ukraine.de/hilfeportal-ua).
Assuming you were an Ukrainian citizen in Ukraine in Feb of 2022 (when the Russians invaded), you can come to Germany as a Refugee. You will get the usual payments for accepted refugees, that includes money to finance your living expenses as well as rent for an appartment. It might not be as amazing as right wing extremists claim, but it is good enough to live by. You also get the right to take up work in Germany.
Obviously, paperwork might take a little time and appartments aren't just empty waiting for tennants either, so you may be housed in a shelter or group home for refugees first, until the paperwork clears and you find an appartment.
But there should never be a day without a roof above the head, sanitary facilities and three meals a day.
If you do not want to register as a refugee, you can stay 90 days Visa free. But obviously, you would have to pay for everything yourself then and try to find a hotel or something similar for short term housing out of your own pocket.

You are giving me a hope. Thanks. BTW me first time see the link you just showed. I asked GPT and it gave only this: BAMF. I'd left an e-form there, mb they will answer after the holidays.

roof above head is more than enough to start off.

BAMF is the correct agency, the page I linked is by them.

Note that in many parts of Germany, finding a home outside the refugee shelter can be difficult even if the social services cover the rent payment. You might spend months living in a small room together with complete strangers. You will have to decide if that is better than what you have now.

@o.m. point taken.

(+1) Technically, the most straightforward status would be temporary protection, that's what the website is talking about. Ukrainians from non-occupied parts of Ukraine are probably also eligible for subsidiary protection under EU law. Both are distinct from an actual refugee status. It would therefore be more accurate to write that the OP is “entitled to protection in Germany”, which is also the terminology used on the official website.
